# Eclipse hung on Mac OS X when clicking on TabItems and then switch to a list

Tags: eclipse, macos, jvm, swt

I'm developing an eclipse plugin on Mac OS X 10.7.3. The UI consists of a TabFolder with 4 TabItems, and some other lists. When I switch between the tabs several times and then clicking another list, eclipse will hung. from the Activity Monitor I could see the CPU usage rushed to 100% and Real Mem also keep increasing. The JVM dump is as below:

```
2012-12-07 10:14:14
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.4-b02-402 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=9 tid=7fa8a4906800 nid=0x116fe7000 waiting on condition [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon prio=5 tid=7fa8a396a000 nid=0x116ae1000 in Object.wait() [116ae0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d0133cb8> (a org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:106)
    - locked <7d0133cb8> (a org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor)

"Worker-3" prio=5 tid=7fa89fe4f000 nid=0x114752000 in Object.wait() [114751000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d43e4648> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <7d43e4648> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

"org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler" daemon prio=1 tid=7fa8a3a7c000 nid=0x11730c000 in Object.wait() [11730b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d5c6c590> (a org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.DirtyRegionQueue)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:179)
    - locked <7d5c6c590> (a org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.DirtyRegionQueue)

"JavaScript indexing" daemon prio=4 tid=7fa8a2aca800 nid=0x11653f000 in Object.wait() [11653e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d576a0c8> (a org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.indexing.IndexManager)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.run(JobManager.java:370)
    - locked <7d576a0c8> (a org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.indexing.IndexManager)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

"Java indexing" daemon prio=4 tid=7fa8a1c47800 nid=0x1169de000 in Object.wait() [1169dd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d50c39d8> (a org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.indexing.IndexManager)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.run(JobManager.java:382)
    - locked <7d50c39d8> (a org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.indexing.IndexManager)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

"Worker-2" prio=5 tid=7fa89f49a000 nid=0x11641b000 in Object.wait() [11641a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d43e4648> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <7d43e4648> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

"Worker-1" prio=5 tid=7fa89f3cc000 nid=0x114dcf000 in Object.wait() [114dce000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d43e4648> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <7d43e4648> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

"Worker-0" prio=5 tid=7fa89d0b0000 nid=0x116169000 in Object.wait() [116168000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d43e4648> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <7d43e4648> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

"Worker-JM" prio=5 tid=7fa89e886000 nid=0x113f33000 in Object.wait() [113f32000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d4277db8> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.InternalWorker.run(InternalWorker.java:58)
    - locked <7d4277db8> (a java.util.ArrayList)

"Bundle File Closer" daemon prio=5 tid=7fa89b33f000 nid=0x114baf000 in Object.wait() [114bae000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d447b468> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
    - locked <7d447b468> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

"[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon prio=5 tid=7fa89ec29800 nid=0x114ef4000 in Object.wait() [114ef3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d42e9a50> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.timer.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:141)
    - locked <7d42e9a50> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

"Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon prio=5 tid=7fa89b2f9800 nid=0x1141c6000 in Object.wait() [1141c5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d43147f0> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
    - locked <7d43147f0> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

"Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon prio=5 tid=7fa89e90b800 nid=0x11464f000 in Object.wait() [11464e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d4314870> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
    - locked <7d4314870> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

"State Data Manager" daemon prio=5 tid=7fa89b15c000 nid=0x113ce4000 waiting on condition [113ce3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.StateManager.run(StateManager.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

"Framework Active Thread" prio=5 tid=7fa89b157800 nid=0x113be1000 in Object.wait() [113be0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d4021de0> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.run(Framework.java:1862)
    - locked <7d4021de0> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

"Poller SunPKCS11-Darwin" daemon prio=1 tid=7fa89c10c800 nid=0x112448000 waiting on condition [112447000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11$TokenPoller.run(SunPKCS11.java:692)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

"Thread-1" daemon prio=6 tid=7fa89c002800 nid=0x7fff734ca960 runnable [7fff68d24000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDownSuper(Widget.java:1093)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List.mouseDownSuper(List.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDown(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseDown(Control.java:2538)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5493)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowSendEvent(Widget.java:2102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowSendEvent(Shell.java:2299)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5557)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationSendEvent(Display.java:5002)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5151)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.sendEvent(NSApplication.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3616)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=5 tid=7fa89e80b000 nid=0x111ed4000 runnable [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=9 tid=7fa89e80a800 nid=0x111dd1000 waiting on condition [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=9 tid=7fa89e809800 nid=0x111cce000 waiting on condition [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JDWP Command Reader" daemon prio=5 tid=7fa89b0c9000 nid=0x111bcb000 runnable [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon prio=5 tid=7fa89b0c7000 nid=0x111ac8000 runnable [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon prio=5 tid=7fa89b0c8000 nid=0x1119c5000 runnable [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=9 tid=7fa89b0c5800 nid=0x1118bc000 runnable [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon prio=5 tid=7fa89b0c4800 nid=0x1117b9000 waiting on condition [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=7fa89d041800 nid=0x1114f5000 in Object.wait() [1114f4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d4024710> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked <7d4024710> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=7fa89d041000 nid=0x1113f2000 in Object.wait() [1113f1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7d4020878> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
    - locked <7d4020878> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=5 tid=7fa89b001000 nid=0x1099f9000 runnable [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"VM Thread" prio=9 tid=7fa89d03c000 nid=0x1112ef000 runnable 

"Gang worker#0 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7fa89b002800 nid=0x10cd72000 runnable 

"Gang worker#1 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7fa89b003000 nid=0x10ce75000 runnable 

"Gang worker#2 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7fa89b003800 nid=0x10cf78000 runnable 

"Gang worker#3 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7fa89b004000 nid=0x10d07b000 runnable 

"Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC Thread" prio=9 tid=7fa89b07f800 nid=0x110f90000 runnable 
"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=7fa89e81d000 nid=0x111fd7000 waiting on condition 

"Exception Catcher Thread" prio=10 tid=7fa89b001800 nid=0x109b99000 runnable 
JNI global references: 11239
```

Does any one have idea on what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation i finally found the root cause. It's not caused by the Tab but the List. When clicking on the empty area on a list (the list has more rows than entries), the list.getSelection() will still be the current selected item on Windows, but will be empty on Mac. And when retrieving the value by list.getSelection()[0], eclipse will hang instead of throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(). I've worked around this issue by remembering the current selection with local variable and set the selection when user clicked on empty areas.